# ¿Cómo selecciono todos los campos según el id de usuario en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

En una vista quiero que el usuario solo pueda ver los campos añadidos por él y no el de otros.
En un controlador he intentado de muchas maneras de que me llame todos los registros mientras el **userId** de la table negocios sea igual al id de la persona conectada pero la vista me aparece en blanco teniendo el **foreach** listo y funcionando si solo dejo **::all** .

```
public function negocios(){
    
        $negocios = App\Negocio::where('userId', auth()->id());
        return view('negocio.minegocio', compact('negocios'));
    }
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer? Estoy usando laravel 7, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando como base la consulta que ya tienes, simplemente debes obtener al final la colección total de negocios cuya llave foránea sea igual al id del usuario que inició sesión de esta forma:

```
$negocios = App\Negocio::where('userId', auth()->id())->get();
```

No logras iterar nada en la vista por que la salida sin el método `get()` no es algo iterable; de hecho si imprimes directo en el controlador tu consulta actual esta sería la salida:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
```

- Te recomiendo leas [como agregar constrainst adicionales en una consulta con Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#adding-additional-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

te puedo dar una idea de como lo he realizado en otros proyectos.

Primero debes modificar el archivos app/User.php

Ejemplo: app/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idusuarios';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','isAdmin'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Luego desde el controlador o desde el modelo puedes llamar la siguiente función para obtener los atributos del usuario, ejemplo:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

```
$idusuario = Auth::user()->idusuarios
```

Así quedaría tu código

```
public function negocios(){

        $negocios = App\Negocio::where('userId', $idusuario);
        return view('negocio.minegocio', compact('negocios'));
    }
```

Espero te sirva.